# How to use HTML in Markdown?

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll

Using Jeykll, I have a markdown file with a div and a list inside it.

The problem is that by introducing the div into the markdown, the list loses its markdown "styling":

```
some text here <a href="#anchor-text-here" data-toggle="collapse" href="#anchor-text-here" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="anchor-text-here">some text here</a>.

<div id="anchor-text-here" class="collapse">
1. step 1
2. step 2
3. step 3  and so on... 
</div>
```

The generated HTML does not contain the OL element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the solution is to add an attribute: `markdown="1"` to the DIV element, as apparently markdown gets "disabled" if put inside a DIV element.